# Getting the value of a specific key in an object through a function

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

As an exercise, I am trying to write a function called `getValue()` which takes two parameters, `obj` and `key`.

This is unrelated to getting an index of an object by its property.

The function should pass in the name of an object (`obj`) and the name of an object property (`key`), the return the value associated with that property. If there is no value (that is, the property does not exist in the object), `getValue()` should return undefined. As long as the named property does exist, the function should return its associated value.

I wrote a function that works but only if the property is named `key`. Which of course is not what I had in mind.

```js
function getValue(obj, key) {
 this.obj = {};
 this.key = obj.key;
 const val = function() {
  return obj.key;
 };
 return val();
}

var theObject = {nokey: 'my_value'};
var output = getValue(theObject, 'nokey');
console.log(output);
// --> 'should return 'my_value' but
// but returns undefined
```

Comment: I looked but could not find an answer to this precise question before. Link?

Comment: I really don't see how the linked-to question & answer relates to creating a function that returns the value of a property from an object by passing in the name of the object and the name of the key.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're passed the object itself, just access the property with bracket notation:

```js
function getValue(obj, key) {
  return obj[key];
}

var theObject = {nokey: 'my_value'};
console.log(getValue(theObject, 'nokey'));

var object2 = {foo: 'bar'};
console.log(getValue(object2, 'baz'));
```

Comment: Duh. Embarrassingly easy solution. Thanks.